# svn:externals a sub-folder of a git project

Tags: svn, git, github, svn-externals

is there a way to get only a part (ex: a sub-folder called **/library**) of a github.com project and use it in **svn:externals**?

What I'm doing now is

```
$svn pe svn:externals .
   SomeLibrary http://svn.github.com/myuser/myproject.git
```

But I don't want everything from the project... I need something like:

```
$svn pe svn:externals .
   SomeLibrary http://svn.github.com/myuser/myproject.git/library
```

Comment: What happens when you do it exactly as you quote? Provided git are providing a proper SVN interface, that should work fine.

Comment: Even if I put a valid path after myproject.git/././. , svn ignores it and downloads the whole project from its root.. :/
example: 

"svn checkout http://svn.github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine.git/library lib"

OBS: but if try an invalid path, ex:
"svn checkout http://svn.github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine.git/WRONGPATH lib",
I get a svn: URL 'http://svn.github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine.git/WRONGPATH' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now supported on GitHub.

With no subpath specified the entire repo is fetched:

```
$ svn co https://github.com/myuser/myproject
A    myproject/branches
A    myproject/trunk
A    myproject/trunk/README.md
A    myproject/trunk/library
A    myproject/trunk/library/myproject.rb
A    myproject/trunk/library/myproject
A    myproject/trunk/library/myproject/sample.rb
Checked out revision 1.
```

And with a subpath specified, only that part of the repo is fetched:

```
$ svn co https://github.com/myuser/myproject/trunk/library
A    library/myproject.rb
A    library/myproject
A    library/myproject/sample.rb
Checked out revision 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Github support has just replied my question:

> this isn't possible, git is an
>   all-or-nothing affair, you can't grab
>   just a subpath.

Comment: This is no longer true fortunately :)